# How to add another object to a collection?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a function that adds 'bookings' to a firebase document. In the image below, it can be seen that there's already an object inside of the bookings/date. I want to add another one.

This would make it in an array of objects (?)

[image: collection firebase]

So far, my attemps have only overwritten what's in there or created a subcollectioin with the name bookings

```
const bookingObj = {
      ...cartItems[1],
      userId: userObject.uid,
      carro: 'PASSA_CARRO',
      cor: 'PASSAR_COR',
    }

const businessRef = await approvedBusinessService.doc(businessId)
const bookingDateRef = await businessRef.collection('bookings').doc(currentDate) //currentDate: "15/06/2020"
    try {
      bookingDateRef.set(bookingObj) //will create a subcollection
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error merging Business info')
    }
```

Previously, I had `{ merge: true }` but that was also not behaving as I wished.

Comment: FYI: Your try/catch isn't handling any Firestore errors. `set()` and `update()` each return a promise, and you will need to use that promise to determine if there was an error in the usual JavaScript way.

Answer (score 1):

"bookings" is not a collection, it's a document field.  So you can't refer to it using `collection()`.  If you had a subcollection, it would appear very differently in the console.  (And it's strongly worth considering making it a subcollection instead of a field, especially if you can add unbounded lists of objects under it.)

If you want to add a new nested field under bookings, you will have to update the document and call out the name of the nested field to update using dot notation.

```
const businessRef = approvedBusinessService.doc(businessId)
await businessRef.update(`bookings.${currentDate}`, bookingObj)
```

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting an error and when I try to log the error. All it comes back is 'NaN'. Probably has to do with your comment above. How to go about being able to see the error to then correct it?

Comment: Sorry, that's not enough information to work with.  I am borrowing as much as I can from the code you've shown, but without seeing all the values of the variables, there is not much I can do.  You'll have to put some effort into debugging.

Comment: I'd like to add another object to ```15/06/2020```, but your code is simply updating the object that is already there. Perhaps I should do something different?

Comment: Figure out what you want to use instead of currentDate.   Your will have to build the field path using dot notation.  It sounds like you want "bookings.15/06/2020".